# onchange in onchange won't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

When I am building 2 dropdowns filling them from the database, the second dropdown is created when a value is picked from the first dropdown. But then, when I select an option in the second, my ajax is being executed. But when I have only one value in the second dropdown, it won't work. Even if I call the javascript function manualy.

The 2nd dropdown:

```
<?
include ('../dbconnect.php');
$query = "CALL get_projects(".$userid.",".$q.")";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$countprojects = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($countprojects != 0){

    echo '<select class="form-control" onchange="showContent(this.value)">'."\n";
    if ($countprojects > 1){
        echo "<option value='none' selected>Select project</option>";
    }
    while($rowprojecten = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<option value='.$rowprojecten['projectID'].'>'.$rowprojecten['projectname'].'</option>';
        $lastvalue = $rowprojecten['projectID']; // see below why i did this
    }

    echo '</select>';

?>
```

the javascript function I wrote/copied:

```
function showContent(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("project").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("project").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","./includes/ajax/getcontent.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The phpfile what is called from this javascript:

```
<?
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

include ('../dbconnect.php');

$query = "CALL get_project(".$userid.",".$q.")";

$return = '<div id="project">';
$return .= $query;
$return .= '</div>';

echo $return;

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Why do I see the div 'project' change when I select one, but does'nt it change when it is created?

I tried to call the function manualy with adding this to the first php file. But it also doesn't work.

```
if ($countprojects == 1){ 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        showContent('.$lastvalue.')
        </script>';
}
```

sorry for my bad english, I hope you can help me solve this.

Comment: The MySQL extension Officially deprecated. You should use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: `@$countprojects = mysql_num_rows($result);` - NO! Remove the `@`. When will people stop doing this?

Comment: Changed it for you. But it's not the problem.

Comment: is this HyperText prePROCESSOR?

Comment: @Mart-Jan: I know it's not the problem, I'm just trying to get you out of bad habits.

Comment: I don't know all about preprocessing. I'm not that experienced with that. Does it make sense for my problem?

Comment: @PeteR thank you. I need to get out of a lot of bad habits. That's where my lessons at school are for ;)

Comment: For now, I don't need to fix this. But it is so much better in my opinion to not have to choose a project when there is only one project to choose. I want to display the only one. But I do not need it that much. If anybody has a complete working answer, please post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is only one option in your second drop down list. you cannot fire change event if there is only on or zero options in drop down list. what you can do is add this code where your first Ajax call get fired when selection changes. and place your second Ajax call in inside below code.

```
if ($('#selectproject').children().length == 1) {

            // make sure you have imported latest jquery. if not add this inside HTMl head  : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            var selectedProject = $('#selectproject').children()[0].value;
            showContent(selectedProject); // i hope this is the function you are calling when executing. if not please replace your function call here.
        }
```

Comment: Can you help me a little more? I added id="selectproject" to my select in the first script. Then i added it to <code>if ($('#selectproject').children().length == 1)</code> and I copied all the code from the javascript. Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: if ($('#selectproject').children().length == 1) {

            // make sure you have imported latest jquery. if not add this inside HTMl head  : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            var selectedProject = $('#selectproject').children()[0].value;
            showContent(selectedProject); // i hope this is the function you are calling when executing. if not please replace your function call here.
        } 
Hope This will fix your problem.

Comment: Let Me Know If You Fixed It Or Not :)

Comment: It still doesn't work. I really don't understand why.

Comment: Can You Paste full HTML file source in here. So i can look into it.

Comment: Did You Import Jquery ? If you not familier with jquery i can provide with you pure javascript solution.

Comment: I did import the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> as you told me. I am looking for an option to share the code. There are a lot of files and query's used.

Comment: I added you on skype. If I post all the content here, it won't work I think

Comment: I Cannot Use Skype Right Now. But Maybe after few hours i will be online. i will help you then.